# <select> with ngRepeat dont select item when first element selected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-select

I'm facing a problem when using `ngRepeat` and `ngSelected` inside `<select>` tag, this is the code:

```
<select ng-model="y.SkuId" ng-change="y.Edited=true;">
    <option ng-repeat="s in skus" ng-selected="s.Key == y.SkuId" value="{{s.Key}}">{{s.Value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

This works fine when the selected item is other than the first item, but when the selected is the first one, outputs wrong, instead that the html looks good

```
<option ng-repeat="s in skus" ng-selected="s.Key == y.SkuId" 
value="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope" selected="selected">001
```

[image: Output image in explorer]

Note: the numbers are the values (not the index)

**Update**

Now I noticed that only when the last one item in options has the `ngSelected` equals true, browsers displays fine

This is the skus data:

```
[{ "Key" : 1, "Value" : "001" }, { "Key" : 2, "Value" : "002" }]
```

**Update 2**

plnkr with example of error

http://plnkr.co/edit/g8hRHzt1k54ingQdMHHY?p=preview

Comment: Can you include the data for the skus variable you're iterating over?

Comment: [{ "Key" : 1, "Value" : "001" }, { "Key" : 2, "Value" : "002" }]

Comment: Is `y` object initialized ? You may want to create a plnkr

Comment: Test if using integer value instead object works. I already faced a similar problem

Comment: @bhantol y is initialized is element of upper ng-repeater for a table

Comment: @rogeriolino I need to use object with integer and string combination, because value could be other than the integer as string

Comment: Small plnkr would get you quick answer. I suggest you create one.

Comment: @scumbag right, but is just for tests propose. if with integer will work.

Comment: @bhantol here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/g8hRHzt1k54ingQdMHHY?p=preview

Comment: You need to change `value` to something that will evaluate later. `ng-attr` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-attr-value="s.Key"` instead of `value="{{s.Key}}"`.

Try [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTpncP2gzlKNRLSUl72u?p=preview)

Notice the difference is just the value:

```
<select ng-model="k.Key" >
  <option ng-repeat="s in skus" ng-selected="s.Key === k.Key" 
     ng-attr-value="s.Key">{{s.Value}}</option>
</select>
```

The expression evaluation time using {{}} and the ng-repeat compile time are not in sync as one may think. This explain why only the last was selected.

While according to [official documentation - choosing between ng-options and ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) you can use ng-repeat for ng-options but in the cases when you are dealing with objects instead of Ids you may like to use `select as` syntax. Also there are other performance reasons why you may want to do so.

Comment: This solution works fine, I select it as the answere because in addition explain whats happended

Answer (score 2):

try to use *ngOptions* within *select* element instead of *ngRepeat* directive:

```
<select ng-model="d.SkuId"
        ng-options="s.Key as s.Value for s in skus">
</select>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TQIxqSv9ZBleLeA2h6WQ?p=preview